# Unity не отображает функцию в поле onClick(), когда я пытаюсь вернуть 2 значения

Tags: c#, unity3d-editor

```
public void _fieldCounter (InputField inputField, GameObject thisGM) 
   {
     if(inputField.text == Answer[_BTmpSecond]){
        _counter(thisGM); //_counter - другая функция.
   }
     else{}
}
```

Повесил скрипт на объект Counter, поместил его в onClick() на кнопку. Выбираю функцию в выпадающем списке, а её там нет. Когда я убираю GameObject либо InputField из возвращаемых значений - всё отображается нормально. Не могу понять в чём проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я уже нашёл ответ. Это ограничение фреймворка. 2 аргумента передать действительно нельзя. Беда (

Comment: Это не ограничение, а то что вы не можете так просто менять сигнатуры методов, либо вы пишите свой метод обёртку, либо пользуетесь тем что есть.